# How to select a folder from the gallery in Android

Tags: java, android, android-gallery

I found several ways to select pictures from the gallery, but I need to select a folder, I´m trying with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    
intent.setDataAndType(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, DocumentsContract.Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR);

startActivityForResult(intent , 0);
```

and

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    switch(requestCode) {
        case 0:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                Log.v("test", selectedImage.toString());
            }

            break;
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

`android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=content://media/... typ=vnd.android.document/directory }`

Comment: A gallery is an app. Whether a gallery offers folders, or what those folders represent, is up to the developer of the gallery app. There are lots of gallery apps, both pre-installed and user-installed. None have to provide an API for accessing its concept of folders. If you mean you are looking to have the user select something akin to a directory on a filesystem, use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree`.